# Really unfair coin

Tags: probability

I'm stuck here.  I'm trying to figure out what the probability of a really unfair coin where the $P(H)=\frac{1}{10}$.  What is the chance that after 100 flips, you have gotten exactly $2$ heads?

Comment: The binomial distribution calculations work even for unfair coins.

Comment: $\frac{100!}{2!(98!)}(\frac{1}{10})^2\cdot(\frac{9}{10})^{98}$

Comment: Remember that in general if $p$ is the probability of heads on a single toss and you toss a total of $n$ times, the probability of obtaining exactly $k$ heads is $\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}}$.